# Are beets related to turnips?

Tags: beets

We recently made fresh beets, which was a new experience for me, and I was surprised to discover that a freshly cooked fresh beet tastes quite like a similarly cooked turnip. Is there any connection between the two foods?

Comment: There is probably an earthiness and sweetness in both vegetables that makes them similar when cooked.

Comment: Not quite an answer to the question but there is a pickle called lefet very common in the Middle East made of turnips pickled with a beetroot. The beetroot changes the colour of the turnips to a bright pink colour. It's served as a condiment and is very common in falafel sandwiches.

Answer (score 5):

From a scientific standpoint they are not closely related.  They aren't even in the same order.  Beets are order Caryophyllales and Turnips are order Brassicales.